# File within a root grandparent is detected by emacs as belonging to a directory that doesn't exists

Tags: text-editing, permissions

I'm editing a file within a directory `/parentdir/userdir/file` with the following permissions:

```
$ sudo namei -l $(pwd)
drwxr-xr-x   root   root   /
drwx------   root   root   parentdir
drwx--S---   myuser myuser userdir
-rw-------   myuser myuser file
```

Additionally, both `parentdir` and `userdir` have set a `facl` rule that, by default, creates files and directories without any permission for group or others. In any case, my PWD is `/parentdir/userdir` and I have full permissions to edit `file`.

However, if I edit `file` using `emacs`, when trying to save the changes, it says to me that the directory `/parentdir/userdir/` doesn't exists, and asks me if I want to create it.

How can I skip that message in a safe way? Maybe the reason is that `emacs` is trying to save the file using absolute paths, and it gets confuses since it has no execute permissions to access that directory.

Comment: Assuming you're `myuser`, how are you in that directory, when you have no permission to be there?  I presume you're suggesting that other programs are allowing you to write to that file? Can you provide a recipe to reproduce this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is poorly written, but yes, that error is because there's no way to traverse into the directory.

Comment: Sorry I'm not a native english speaker and sometimes it's hard for me to use it properly. Feel free to improve it :D By the way, isn't there a way to force `emacs` to use relative paths when saving files instead of resolving their real paths?